# WPF: Selecting the Target of an Animation

Tags: wpf, data-binding, animation

I am trying to create a simple (I think) animation effect based on a property change in my ViewModel.  I would like the target to be a specific textblock in the control template of a custom control, which inherits from Window.

From the article examples I've seen, a DataTrigger is the easiest way to accomplish this. It appears that Window.Triggers doesn't support DataTriggers, which led me to try to apply the trigger in the style.  The problem I am currently having is that I can't seem to target the TextBlock (or any other child control)--what happens is which the code below is that the animation is applied to the background of the whole window.

If I leave off StoryBoard.Target completely, the effect is exactly the same.

Is this the right approach with the wrong syntax, or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

```
<Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyWindowTemplate}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ChangeOccurred}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}}"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                        <ColorAnimation FillBehavior="Stop" From="Black" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.5" AutoReverse="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Update**

Should have also mentioned that I tried to name the TextBlock and reference it via StoryBoard.TargetName (as Timores suggested), and got the error "TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter."

Comment: What exactly is your desired animation target? You say *"a specific textblock in the control template of a custom control"*, but then create a style for a `Window` and not a custom control. Could you provide the code containing your animation target? The Target Binding above should not work since I do not expect the Window to have an ancestor of type TextBlock, does it?! Is this possible at all?

Comment: Sorry, it's a difficult setup to describe.  The custom control *is* a window, as it derives from window.  The setup/style was created by someone else, so I am trying to retrofit this animation.  The Textblock is a child control--looking at this again, the RelativeSource/AncestorType is probably not even close, since I am trying to target a child and not a parent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** I have overseen the fact that the `TextBlock` is in the `ControlTemplate` of your custom Window/Control. I do not think that it is possible to target a control *within* the `ControlTemplate` from a `Storyboard` *outside* of this `ControlTemplate`. You could however define a property on your custom Window which you then databind to your `ChangeOccurred` property, and then add the trigger to your `ControlTemplate` which will now get triggered by the custom Control's property rather than the Window's ViewModel's property (of course, indirectly it is triggered by the ViewModel because `ChangeOccurred` is bound to the property of the custom Window which in turn triggers the animation - uh, complex sentence, hope you understand). Is this an option? Could you follow? ;-)

Maybe some code helps:

```
public class MyCustomWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChangeOccurred2 = DependencyProperty.Register(...);

    public bool ChangeOccurred2 { ... }

    // ...
}
```

And some XAML:

```
<local:MyCustomWindow ChangeOccurred2="{Binding ChangeOccurred}" ... >
    <!-- Your content here... -->
</local:MyCustomWindow>

<!-- Somewhere else (whereever your ControlTemplate is defined) -->
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomWindow}">

    <!-- your template here -->

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ChangeOccurred2" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0:0:2"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="txtWhatever"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                        <ColorAnimation FillBehavior="Stop"
                                        From="Black" To="Red"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                        AutoReverse="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Note:** I named the Window's property `ChangeOccurred2` because I wanted it to be distinguishable from the ViewModel's `ChangeOccurred` property. Of course, you should choose a better name for this property. However, I am missing the background for such a decision.

---

**My old answer:**

So, you want to animate a `TextBlock` which is in the content of a (custom) Window?!

Why do you want to set the style on the Window, and not on the `TextBlock` itself? Maybe you should try something like this (did not test this!):

```
<local:MyCustomWindow ... >
    <!-- ... -->
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockAnimated" ... >
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ChangeOccurred}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0:0:2"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <ColorAnimation FillBehavior="Stop"
                                                    From="Black" To="Red"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                    AutoReverse="True"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <!-- ... -->
</local:MyCustomWindow>
```

The `{Binding ChangeOccurred}` might not be sufficient. You might have to add a `DataContext` to the `TextBlock`, or add a `RelativeSource` or something.

Comment: Your updated answer works!  Thanks for your help.  I felt like the way I was approaching it was backwards, but I am very new to styling/animating in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Is the TextBlock in the MyWindowTemplate ?

If so, give the TextBlock a name and use Storyboard.TargetName to reference it.

See [another question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151752/storyboards-cant-find-controltemplate-elments)

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I tried that and got: "TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter."

Comment: Also: yes, it's in the control template.