# Name cannot be found in the name scope of ---Error When displaying animation in datagrid

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that displays some data. Based on some conditions I need to animate some particular cell in the `DataGrid`. So I created a user control that contains a label and given some animations.
 Then I displayed this animated label in the datagrid using Template columns.
When I want to start the animation I will loop through the visual tree  and find the user control and will call the `StartAnimation` function.But here I am getting an error

'lblLabel' Name cannot be found in the name scope of system.windows.controls.label.

On searching I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151752/storyboards-cant-find-controltemplate-elments)  and [here](http://www.cplotts.com/2008/09/26/dr-wpf-namescopes/). but no help.

I can animate this control when I place it on a window. But problem occurs when I use within a datagrid.

can anyone shed some lights on this issue. 
Or Is there any better way to animate a Cell of datagrid ?

Answer (score 3):

After a whole day work I solved this issue.

Previously the xaml code for the datagrid was like this :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyHeader">    
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.cellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <my:mycontrol content="{binding mybinding}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.cellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyHeader">
```

here i haven't declared name for MyControl 
so changing the statement

```
<my:mycontrol content="{binding mybinding}">
```

to

```
<my:mycontrol x:Name="lblLabel"content="{binding mybinding}">
```

solved my problem.
I hope this will help someone else.