# Name of subcontrol in custom control not found

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I am using WPF 4.5.2 C# 7 in .Net 4.7.2

I want to add a EventTrigger with a StoryBoard animation by code. 
In Xaml it would look like this (tested, working)

```
<!-- in the control template -->
<Viewport3D x:Name="PART_Viewport" Visibility="Hidden" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">       
    <!-- ... -->        
</ViewPort>


<!-- in the trigger -->
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:MyCustomControl.MyEvent">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Viewport"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <!-- ... -->
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>      
</EventTrigger>
```

In the custom control class it looks like this

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    DiscreteObjectKeyFrame frameStart = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame() { KeyTime = new TimeSpan( 0 , 0 , 0 ) , Value = Visibility.Visible , };
    DiscreteObjectKeyFrame frameEnd = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame() { KeyTime = new TimeSpan( 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 100 ) , Value = Visibility.Hidden , };

    ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames()
    {
        Name = "PART_ViewPort"
    };

    Storyboard.SetTargetName( objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames , "PART_Viewport" );
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty( objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames , new PropertyPath( "Visibility" ) );

    objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add( frameStart );
    objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add( frameEnd );
}
```

Creating the EventTrigger works fine, but calling throws this error
"The name "PART_Viewport" can not be found in the namespace of MyNameSpace.MyCustomControl"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpfully.

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `Storyboard.SetTargetName`?

Comment: Please have a look at the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't understood every detail of your example, but I have managed to generate a very similar error.

I have defined a custom control called vp3d, with a routed event Tap. At the place where the custom control is used, I have specified an event handler, as follows:

```
<cc:vp3d Grid.Row="2">
  <cc:vp3d.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="cc:vp3d.Tap">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Viewport"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <!-- ... -->
          </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </cc:vp3d.Triggers>
</cc:vp3d>
```

PART_Viewport is defined in the ControlTemplate.

You can access this name using the method GetTemplateChild within the custom control, but I don't think you can refer to it from outside the custom control.

However, if I add the following code to the OnApplyTemplate method in the custom control, it seems to fix the problem.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate ( )
{
  base.OnApplyTemplate ();

  var vp = GetTemplateChild ("PART_Viewport") as Viewport3D;
  RegisterName ("PART_Viewport", vp ) ;
}
```

This is based on an idea in [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151752/storyboards-cant-find-controltemplate-elements). If this doesn't work for you, the other answers in that thread may help.

Comment: Thanks Phil, I didn't call RegisterName, which caused the error.
. 
  var vp = GetTemplateChild ("PART_Viewport") as Viewport3D;
  RegisterName ("PART_Viewport", vp ) ;
.
are the relevant lines

Answer (score -1):

You should add object in storyboard children:

```
StoryBoardObject.Children.Add(objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do so later on, I just didn't show that line, because no error is raised when keyframes are added to the storyboard. The error is never thrown when the Eventtrigger happens to be created, but it is called and the animation should run.